# Code First update-database blows up production after application pool reset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I've been having this issue for quite some time and had adopted to adding database fields via Code First and publishing to production at the start of a development sprint to ensure the production site would not blow up after I had updated the database context. After application reset, the application would recognize the missing changes in the code base. I want to hide these changes to the context from production until I'm ready to publish.

What is the correct method to add a Code First field in my local environment? Let's say I'm working on a new part of my website and I'm adding new entities and fields to my existing Code First classes (example: adding `Gender` to a `Person` entity). How would I do this so that I would not need to publish to production to update that code base if production is using the same database? How would I simply have production ignore the new database field?

(P.S.) I know it is definitely not wise to have one database for dev and production, but this is the current situation which is being improved upon.

Comment: Just install SQL Express on your development machine and work with that. Migrations store metadata in the database so dev and prod clash. You do. not. want. to work this way. Imagine you accidentally a column.

Comment: Okay, that is where I was going. I just wanted to make sure there weren't any other short term solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know of code first migrations

I think you need  to look at this, after you have delivered your first model to production database,

you need to work with this to handle changes to schema:   [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/data/jj591621.aspx#enabling)